# Why could the following library function make a call to a nonstatic member fuction without create an object?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, gnulib

pb_ds (`<ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>` and 4 other headers) is a GNU C++ library for some data structures(e.g. red black tree). And I encountered the code of applying update when the tree is modified:

```
PB_DS_CLASS_T_DEC
template<typename Node_Update_>
inline void
PB_DS_CLASS_C_DEC::
apply_update(node_pointer p_nd, Node_Update_*  /*p_update*/)
{
  node_update::operator()(node_iterator(p_nd),
              node_const_iterator(static_cast<node_pointer>(0)));
}
```

where the `node_update` class is of the following form:

```
template<class Node_CItr,class Node_Itr,class Cmp_Fn,class _Alloc>
struct my_node_update
{
    typedef my_type metadata_type;
    void operator()(Node_Itr it, Node_CItr end_it)
    {
        //...
    }
};
```

and I was confused about the code `node_update::operator()...` which  I think calls a non-static member function from the `node_update` class, but did not create an object. So how did the call work?

Comment: `apply_update` is also a member function, perhaps `node_update` is a base class?

Comment: There's not enough context to do more than guess. One example: If those all-caps identifiers (`PB_DS_CLASS_T_DEC` and `PB_DS_CLASS_C_DEC`) are macros, the code the compiler sees after pre-processing could be vastly different than what we see.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know *exactly* without seeing the full definition of `PB_DS_CLASS_C_DEC` but `::` is the scope resolution operator so it is using the rules for [qualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup) to more fully specify under what scope the compiler should find the function `operator()` which is in this case `node_update`.

It's unclear without more context if `node_update` is a base class of `PB_DS_CLASS_C_DEC`, a namespace, a static member, or what.

I did find code almost the same as what you've pasted [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/ext/pb_ds/detail/pat_trie_/update_fn_imps.hpp#L53)

which looks like:

```
PB_DS_CLASS_T_DEC
template<typename Node_Update_>
inline void
PB_DS_CLASS_C_DEC::
apply_update(node_pointer p_nd, Node_Update_*)
{
  Node_Update_::operator()(node_iterator(p_nd, this),
               node_const_iterator(0, this));
}
```

If it is indeed an error that your code has `node_update` instead of `Node_Update_` then they're instructing the compiler to utilize `operator()` in the templated type `Node_Update_` which will presumably be deduced based on the arguments passed to apply_update.

From the above repo, `apply_update` is private and is always passed `this` as the second argument cast to a `node_update` type that the class itself is templated on and also publicly inherits from.

So the end result is that `Node_Update_` always appears to be a base class and they're specifying which base type specifically to call `operator()` on.